# How to save edited PyQt5 TableWidget cell?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have an Application which has a QTableWidget. When the user clicks a cell he can edit it, and can write anything. When he is finished he presses the 'enter' key to finish editing the cell.

I want to get the new cell value right after the enter key and save it to a file with the keypress.

```
    #keyPressEvent
    self.tableWidget.keyPressEvent = self.KeyPressed

def KeyPressed(self,event):
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        col = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
        print(self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text())
```

This is the keypress code, but it gets the old value when the key pressed.

Any solution for this, or any other way to save the edited cell to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call this in your main class:

```
self.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.save_changes)

@pyqtSlot()
def save_changes(self):
    for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
        projectName = self.tableWidget.item(currentQTableWidgetItem.row(),  0).text()
        #save changes to a .csv file with pandas
```

Comment: Hello, this helped a lot!! Can you please check out my new question which is related to your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68634277/how-to-save-changes-to-csv-with-pyqt5-tablewidget-itemchange