# How to save changes to .csv with Pyqt5 TableWidget ItemChange?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, user-interface, pyqt5

I have a data table with columns ['Project_ID','Event_ID','Event_name','Start_Date','End_Date']. I loaded this data table to a QTableWidget, but without ID's (thats only for backend). One project can have multiple events, so in this table there are lot of duplicate 'Project_ID', but all the 'Event_ID' are unique.

User journey: User click on a project, it opens a new window (Project_ID is passed) with the QTableWidget in the center, and loads the data in from the .csv. User can see/add/remove/modify the Events.

I used ItemChange() signal and pandas .loc[] to save the user changes in a .csv file. However I do not know how to locate the row in the .csv file. I only know the 'Project_ID', and in this signal the Event_name is the new name, so I cant get the old variable to locate my row in the data table.

Note: I want the user to be able to modify all three columns, and save the changes.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('demo.ui',self)

        self.located_ID = "455346ab-134d-4ab5-81ad-3ed4b365a8b8" #This comes from the Main Form


        self.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.save_changes)

        self.projekt_events = pd.read_csv('Adatok/esemenyek.csv',sep=';',encoding='utf-8')
        self.projekt_events = self.projekt_events.loc[self.projekt_events['UUID_Projekt']==self.located_ID]  #I kknow this ID from the main Form
        tableWidgetItems = pd.DataFrame(self.projekt_events,columns=['ESEMENY','KEZDO_DATE','VEGE_DATE'])
        
        # Adding data to table
        data = tableWidgetItems.values.tolist()
        numrows = len(data)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(numrows)

        for row in range(numrows):
            for column in range(2):
                if isinstance(data[row][column], int):
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row,column, QTableWidgetItem((str(data[row][column]))))   
                else:
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem((data[row][column])))

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def save_changes(self):
        # Dataframe columns = ['Project_ID','Event_ID','Event_name','Start_Date','End_Date']
        #"How do i save First, Second and Third column changes to this csv file<
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget_pdw.selectedItems():
            self.projekt_events.loc[(self.projekt_events['Project_ID']==self.located_ID)&(self.projekt_events['Event_ID']=="?????"),column] = currentQTableWidgetItem.text()
            self.projekt_events.to_csv('Adatok/esemenyek.csv',index=False, encoding='utf-8',sep=';')

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I updated the question with an example, can you please check it out? Maybe you can help me :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, it reads the entire

```
                for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                    rowdata = []
                    for column in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                        item = self.tableWidget.item(row, column)
                        if item is not None:
                            rowdata.append(item.text())
                        else:
                            rowdata.append('')
```